# Display linux terminal colors in windows

Tags: linux, windows, terminal

In Linux terminal, we can use colors, that's totally cool.
Now, I have some Linux script that produces colorful text. I would like to give the output to someone who uses Windows. How can I preserve the colors?

My understanding is that Windows terminal does not support the same kind of color encoding. Installing cygwin is probably too demanding. The output is too long so giving a screenshot is not an option.

Comment: not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the Linux terminal you are using, when copying the colored text from it, it should copy it with color too. For example, copying from Cygwin's MinTTY to Microsoft Word copies it colored.

Anyway, it's called [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), so you can search for editors or terminals for Windows that support ANSI escape codes.

Comment: The "copying" referred to is a screenshot.  If you copied the text using select/paste, the colors would not follow...

Comment: @ThomasDickey I don't understand, I tried and the colors are copied to Word

Comment: hmm - reading the source-code, I see something worth discussing (in the second sentence).  But your answer as given is not.  Start by deleting the first and last sentences, and go read the source for PuTTY to make a proper answer.